# How to separate values in string into Array(s)

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I want to put a string with different data types into separate arrays, suppose I have the following string (In each line, each "field" is separated by a white space " ") :

```
string s = "1 2 3 Hello_world
            3 4 1 Hi_world   
            1 5 3 Bye_world"
```

I want to put this string into 4 separate arrays, each array is the values in each column so it will display something like this when displayed:

```
s[0] = 1, 3, 1
s[1] = 2, 4, 5  
s[2] = 3, 1, 3  
s[3] = Hello_world, Hi_world, Bye_world
```

How do I initialize and achieve these arrays? Other languages have a function called split (C#, PHP etc), what about C++?

Also, I can only use Arrays, not vector. Please someone advice. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string

Comment: C++ has `std::istringstream`

Comment: Make an array of `std::stringstream`s each containing one line. Try figuring out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a string, let's make it a stream:

```
std::istringstream input_stream(s);
```

The pattern seems to be that each row of the string will be the next element of your destination arrays.

```
int a[3];
int b[3];
int c[3];
std::string d[3];

int i;
int index = 0;
input_stream >> i;
a[index] = i;

input_stream >> i;
b[index] = i;

input_stream >> i;
c[index] = i;

std::string t;
input_stream >> t;
d[index] = t;
```

The above fragment is for one iteration.

A task for the OP is to convert the fragment into a loop to process each row of the string.

Comment: I tried your method and tried placing it in a loop ... but it cannot compile and gives the following errors:

cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘int’ in assignment
     a[counter] = s;
     b[counter] = s;
     c[counter] = s;

Following are my codes:

     int a[14];
     int b[14];
     int c[14];
     string d[14];
     int counter = 0;

     istringstream inputStream(s);
     for(string t; inputStream >> t;)  
    {
   a[counter] = t;
   b[counter] = t;
   c[counter] = t;
   d[counter] = t;
    counter++;
 }

Comment: for a more organized look of my codes. please refer to below.

Comment: Don't put code into comments; it becomes difficult to read.  Edit your post with the new text.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Tokenizer routine that can split your string into substrings with your particular separators ("\n" in one case, and " " in the other). Then you can save your resulting substrings into a vector or strings (std::vector vectorOfStrings;)

Have a look at the answers here:

[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your reply. However, is there any other methods other than vector? As I'm trying to do this without using vector.

Comment: You could also use a plain old array: `std::string arrOfStrings[3];`